# Jacobian for Partial Iwasawa Coordinates

Tags: harmonic-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, matrix-calculus

I am working through Terras' Harmonic Analysis, V2, and am stuck on I believe a notational point. We are asked to show that for $$Y=\begin{pmatrix}V&0\\0&W\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I_p&0\\X&I_q\end{bmatrix},$$ then $$J:=\left|\frac{\partial Y}{\partial(V,W,X)}\right|=|W|^p.$$

I assume that $J$ is the determinant of the Jacobian, but I am not sure how to take this, since $V,W,X$ are matrices.

A couple notes: this is excercise 19 in sec. 4.1.3;  $A[B]=B^tAB$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to treat the matrices as vectors. One obtains
$$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial(V,W,X)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  I_{p^2}&\frac{\partial (W[X])}{\partial W}&\frac{\partial (W[X])}{\partial X}\\
  0&\frac{\partial (WX)}{\partial W}&\frac{\partial (WX)}{\partial X}\\
  0&I_{q^2}&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then all that remains is taking $\left|\frac{\partial(WX)}{\partial X}\right|$.